# simple drawing with pyqt on a QGraphicsview

Tags: pyqt, drawing

I'm looking for a simple way to draw a line on a widget within a main window of a QT application.
I designed with QtDesigner a main window with a QGraphicsview and a button. When pressing a button, a line should be drawn in the graphics view. Isn't there a simple way to do so. Is a QGraphicsview the right choice for drawing? I read dozents of articles now and really found no solution. 
Here is my code in short:

```
import sys
import mainwindowui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindowui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.pushButton1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.pb1_pressed)

    def pb1_pressed(self):
        # here I want to draw  a line on the QGraphicswidget: 
        # something simple like: graphview.line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

I saw a lot of very complicated looking solutions and I tried a lot, e.g. with overwriting paintevent using QPainter but got errors like "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1" and I don't know how if this is the right way.
Can someone please give me a really simple solution?
Thank you in advance.

Dieter

Answer (score 2):

The `QGraphicsView` is a widget that is used to display the content of a `QGraphicsScene` so I assume you already have the `QGraphicsScene`. If so, you can draw a line on the `QGraphicsScene` in this way:

```
scene.addLine(QLineF(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

Where scene is a reference to your `QGraphicsScene` instance.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addLine